# Why does python return an AttributeError when I click on a rectangle defined by a text?

Tags: python, pygame

I want my code to react when I click on a text. This is my code defining the text/rectangle:

```
t2 = font.render("YOU ARE BORN", True,"Black", "white")
t2r = t2.get_rect()
t2r.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)
```

And this is where it is executed:

```
running = True
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if t2r.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    print("hello")
```

And when this is run I get this error:

```
    if t2r.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
AttributeError: 'pygame.rect.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t2r` is already a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. So just `t2r.collidepoint` instead of `t2r.rect.collidepoint`:

<s>`if t2r.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):`</s>

```py
if t2r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
```